# Jquery addclass to multiple divs with same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addclass

I have a list (in different styles) multiple times on my site.

Every list-element has a unique data-id /class (same on both lists).($cid is the unique id).

I'd like to add a "selected" class to all the elements that have the same data-id / class.

```
<div id="page">
    [...]
    <div id="printlist">
       <div data-id="pc_{$cid}" class="pc_{$cid} productc">
           <h5>TITLE</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
    [...]
    <div id="footer">
       <div data-id="pc_{$cid}" class="pc_{$cid} productc">
           <h5>SAME TITLE, OTHER POSITION</h5>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I have tried so far:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.productc').click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.'+id).addClass('selceted');
    });
});
```

**Neither this worked:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.productc').click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.'+id).each(function(i){
            $('.'+id).addClass('selceted');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/bbMcF/

Comment: You're aware of the typo in your `addClass()`? 'selceted' rather than 'selected'? This might be the reason you're not seeing the class applied.

Comment: Rolled back the edit, as it fixes the issue that is likely causing your code to fail.

Comment: So it's a typo? selceted instead of selected? Flagged for closing for "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: @KorvinSzanto, seems I have to be more careful with fixing typos in questions :)

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward, I'm not sure whether or not that is the actual issue here, it just could've been, and it looks like the answers here suggest that that is the problem.

Comment: You miss `var` before `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mistype selected, and to affect all the element with the same class
try so use

```
$('.productc .'+$(this).attr('data-id')).addClass('selected');
```

inside the click function

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was definitely too late yesterday..

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.productc').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('.'+id).each(function(i){
            $(this).addClass('selected'); // $(this), not the id element
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also works fine. I chose the other answer as it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, albeit untested:

```
$('li[data-id').filter(function(){
    return this.id == $(this).data('id');
}).addClass('selected');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: Thank you. Haven't tried this one as the other answers work fine.

Comment: They also seem to be a lot more work, and more verbose; but you're quite welcome! :)